# Hibernate includes duplicate parameters in query which breaks orphan removal

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data

Hey guys I got a problem:
I have a Role object which is my parent object

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity(name = "roles")
@Table(name = "roles")
@Builder
@ToString
public class Role implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(columnDefinition = "BINARY(16)")
    UUID roleId;

    @Column(length = 2, updatable = false)
    String brand;

    String name;

    String level;


    /*
    relation implementations
    */
      @ToString.Exclude
      @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
      @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
      @JoinColumn(name = "roleId", referencedColumnName = "roleId")
      @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
      private Set<Capability> capabilities = new HashSet<>();
```

this is how the Capability objects looks like

```
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @Data
    @Entity(name = "capabilities")
    @Table(name = "capabilities")
    @IdClass(CapabilityKey.class)
    @Builder
    public class Capability implements Serializable {

    @Id
    String capabilityCode;

    @Id
    @Column(columnDefinition = "BINARY(16)")
    UUID roleId;
}
```

And this is the composite key class

```
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @Data
    @FieldDefaults(level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
    public class CapabilityKey implements Serializable {

    UUID roleId;

    String capabilityCode;

}
```

Saving and deleting whole role objects is working good. Whenever I want to update a role especially when the update contains to remove some capabilities assigned to a role. I get the following error:

> Could not perform addBatch **[No value specified for parameter 3]**
> [**update role_capabilities set roleId=null where roleId=? and
> capabilityCode=? and roleId=?**]; SQL [update role_capabilities set
> roleId=null where roleId=? and capabilityCode=? and roleId=?]
> org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: Could
> not perform addBatch [No value specified for parameter 3] [update
> role_capabilities set roleId=null where roleId=? and capabilityCode=?
> and roleId=?]; SQL [update role_capabilities set roleId=null where
> roleId=? and capabilityCode=? and roleId=?]

where does hibernate get the second roleId?
It is this query which breaks my update

> DEBUG [Test worker] org.hibernate.SQL: update capabilities set
> roleId=null where roleId=? and capabilityCode=? and roleId=?

When I update a role I just call the save() method provided by spring-data-jpa. I assume that hibernate cant delete the entities which needs to be removed because of the update (the orphans) but I dont know why. Any suggestions how to solve this?